# Prove that $x^4+15x^3+7$ is irreducible over $ \mathbb Q$?

Tags: polynomials, field-theory

I am reasonably comfortable with groups and have just started with fields. This question popped up in an assignment sheet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the polynomial has integer coefficients and is monic, it is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ if and only if it is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$.

Now, if it were reducible, it would be so modulo $p$, for every $p$.

If we try modulo $2$, the polynomial is $x^4+x^3+1$, which has no roots over $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. Let's check for a factorization
\begin{align}
x^4+x^3+1
&=(x^2+ax+1)(x^2+bx+1)\\
&=x^4+(a+b)x^3+abx^2+(a+b)x+1
\end{align}
that requires $a+b=1$ and $a+b=0$, which is contradictory.

Answer (score 3):

Equivalently, we may ask for irreducibility over $\Bbb Z$.
As none of $\pm1, \pm7$ is a root, there is no linear factor, hence we are left with
$$ x^4+15x^3+7=(x^2+ax+b)(x^2+cx+d)$$
Then wlog $b=\pm1$, $d=7b$, so
$$ x^4+15x^3+7=(x^2+ax\pm1)(x^2+cx\pm7)$$
which leads to $$c=-7a,\qquad a+c=15$$
which  is impossible in $\Bbb Z$.

Comment: shouldn't $x^2$ read $x^4$ on the LHS of your first two equations?

Comment: The logic here is tricky, but sound (as witnessed by a deleted comment on here). The last two equations Hagen gave can be solved for $a$ and $c$ in $\mathbb Q$, which might lead one to erroneously suspect that this implies a factorization over $\mathbb Q$. However, he omitted the equation $ac \pm 1 \pm 7 = 0$ given by considering the $x^2$ coefficients; if you include that in the system of equations, it should become unsolvable.

Comment: @RobArthan Yep, thanks

Comment: @DustanLevenstein A solution for $a,c$ in $\Bbb Q$ is irrelevant because I am looking for a factorization in $\Bbb Z[x]$ (see my first "innocous" sentence)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I know, hence "The logic here is tricky, but sound". The point that I was making was that the way you've written it might lead someone to conclude that there is a solution over $\mathbb Q$, which would go in direct contradiction to Gauss's Lemma, since you've clearly demonstrated that there is no solution over $\mathbb Z$.